# Angular routing doesn't display my component

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app with several routes, but they are not working. When I click on the links in the header, only the URL changes, and the corresponding page is not rendered.
When the URL is http://localhost:4200/movies/post, the component should render only "HELLO" but I stay on the home page where is The Godfather movie.

This is my code:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'movies/post',
        component: PostMoviePageComponent
    }
]

export const CoreRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

This is the header:

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/movies">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/movies/post">Add movie</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my CoreModule:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [HeaderComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        CoreRoutingModule
    ],
    exports: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

This is AppRoutingModule:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'home'
    },
    {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomepageComponent
    },
    {
    path: 'movies/post',
    component: PostMoviePageComponent
    },
    {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundPageComponent
    }
    ];

    export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

And this is AppModule:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomepageComponent,
        NotFoundPageComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CoreModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    providers: [MoviesService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what `AppRoutingModule` file have?Can you please add code here?

Comment: It is about relative and absolute paths

Comment: I publish AppRoutingModule.

Comment: I believe you are missing `router-outlet`, can you show your `.html` file?

Comment: This is the problem router outlet. Thank you very much.

Comment: Most routing modules look like this: `@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }`